# AWS RDS storage-full status

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have the MS SQL server in AWS RDS. It has 200 GB space. The cloudwatch shows 2608 MB of the it's Free Storage Space. The function 'sp_spaceused ' shows unallocated_space 149147.09 MB (a little before this space was used - it became unallocated after cleaning up some huge DB tables).

Every backup descreases the Free Storage Space for 200 MBs. There is a probability to get storage-full status of the DB in a couple of days. AWS support keeps silence regarding the relationship between FreeStorageSpace and unallocated_space. Google says that we have to use the SHRINK operation with the TRUNCATEONLY parameter.

If somebody has an experience of using this operation on the AWS server or you know some side effects of this operation, the information would be very appreciated. If you have another suggestion how to deal with this, please let me know.

-Alexander

Comment: allocated != used. Allocated just means it has reserved the space. Is there a reason that you don't want the space allocated? It shouldn't affect the size of your backups at all since you are backing up data.

Comment: We'd like to have enough free storage space to be comfortable and set up CloudWatch Alarm for 30 GBs for example. Now we have 2.5 GB alarm that is very close to the critical situation. Is there any way to return at least a part of unallocated space (that is not used by the DB server) to the FreeStorageSpace?

Comment: you need to monitor for space used rather than allocated space.

Comment: Yes, we want to monitore the free storage space. But this is extremely little space 2608 MB. Because more than 140 GB are reserved by the server and represented as unallocated space.  The question is how to allocate this space back to the Free Storage Space?

Comment: Allocate less space when you set up the instance. RDS is going to allocate all the space you give it. The right way to do this is to monitor the used space and not the allocated space though. Getting worked up over allocated space doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: The thing we're worring about is that AWS can mark the DB with the storage-full state. 

I found in the RDS log:

The free storage capacity for DB Instance: XXX is low at 1% of the provisioned storage [Provisioned Storage: 200 GB, Free Storage: 2.55 GB]. You may want to increase the provisioned storage to address this issue.

What do I need 140 GB unallocated memory in case the server is in storage-full state?